# Only store Cloudinary eager transformations, not the original size

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm working on a site where people can upload images and they of course may upload massive files which will eat up cloudinary storage that isn't necessary for the context of the web app. As such I've got an eager transformation set but it stores both the original size and the transformation. Is there a way to tell Cloudinary to only store the transformed image?

Here is my code:

```
    return cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(data, {
      use_filename: true,
      unique_filename: false,
      folder: body.userId,
      eager: { width: 100, height: 100 }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this to work you use the `transform` property instead of `eager`.

```
return cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(data, {
      use_filename: true,
      unique_filename: false,
      folder: body.userId,
      transformation: { width: 100, height: 100 }
    });
```